# Create a table via JSON output in Python with subfield averaging

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble generating output through more than one input json.

json can contain varied amount of services and pointlists, but they will always have the same amount between them, the amount of services and pointlists depends on the query period. The required output is the list of services, the average of the values of the pointlists found in metric1.json and the sum of the values found in the pointlist of metric2.json. The first field in the pointlist is an epoch, it can be ignored.

These are the jsons:

metric1.json

```
{

    "series": [
        {
            "end": 1634820779000,
            "metric": "trace.metric1",
            "tag_set": [
                "service:service1"
            ],
            "start": 1634813610000,
            "scope": "env:data,service:service1",
            "pointlist": [
                [
                    1634813610000.0,
                    null
                ],
                [
                    1634813640000.0,
                    0.9555554443508555
                ],
                [
                    1634813670000.0,
                    0.3535353535353535
                ]
            ],
            "expression": "avg:trace.metric1{service:service1,env:data}",
            "display_name": "trace.metric1"
        },
        {
            "end": 1634820779000,
            "metric": "trace.metric1",
            "tag_set": [
                "service:service2"
            ],
            "start": 1634813610000,
            "scope": "env:data,service:service2",
            "pointlist": [
                [
                    1634813610000.0,
                    0.2525252525252525
                ],
                [
                    1634813640000.0,
                    0.9784554498754123
                ],
                [
                    1634813670000.0,
                    0.3333333333333333
                ]
            ],
            "expression": "avg:trace.metric1{service:service2,env:data}",
            "display_name": "trace.metric1"
        },
        {
            "end": 1634820779000,
            "metric": "trace.metric1",
            "tag_set": [
                "service:service3"
            ],
            "start": 1634813610000,
            "scope": "env:data,service:service3",
            "pointlist": [
                [
                    1634813610000.0,
                    0.4545454545454545
                ],
                [
                    1634813640000.0,
                    0.8678485124785675
                ],
                [
                    1634813670000.0,
                    0.3654789652145336
                ]           
            ],
            "expression": "avg:trace.metric1{service:service3,env:data}",
            "display_name": "trace.metric1"
        }
    ],
    "to_date": 1634820809000,
    "query": "(avg:trace.metric1{env:data} by {service})",
    "message": "",
    "res_type": "time_series",
    "times": [],
    "from_date": 1634813609000,
    "group_by": [
        "service"
    ],
    "values": []
}
```

metric2.json

```
{

    "series": [
        {
            "end": 1634820779000,
            "metric": "trace.metric2",
            "tag_set": [
                "service:service1"
            ],
            "start": 1634813610000,
            "scope": "env:data,service:service1",
            "pointlist": [
                [
                    1634813610000.0,
                    5
                ],
                [
                    1634813640000.0,
                    4
                ],
                [
                    1634813670000.0,
                    2
                ]
            ],
            "expression": "avg:trace.metric2{service:service1,env:data}",
            "display_name": "trace.metric2"
        },
        {
            "end": 1634820779000,
            "metric": "trace.metric2",
            "tag_set": [
                "service:service2"
            ],
            "start": 1634813610000,
            "scope": "env:data,service:service2",
            "pointlist": [
                [
                    1634813610000.0,
                    8
                ],
                [
                    1634813640000.0,
                    8
                ],
                [
                    1634813670000.0,
                    1
                ]
            ],
            "expression": "avg:trace.metric2{service:service2,env:data}",
            "display_name": "trace.metric2"
        },
        {
            "end": 1634820779000,
            "metric": "trace.metric2",
            "tag_set": [
                "service:service3"
            ],
            "start": 1634813610000,
            "scope": "env:data,service:service3",
            "pointlist": [
                [
                    1634813610000.0,
                    4
                ],
                [
                    1634813640000.0,
                    5
                ],
                [
                    1634813670000.0,
                    3
                ]           
            ],
            "expression": "avg:trace.metric2{service:service3,env:data}",
            "display_name": "trace.metric2"
        }
    ],
    "to_date": 1634820809000,
    "query": "(avg:trace.metric2{env:data} by {service})",
    "message": "",
    "res_type": "time_series",
    "times": [],
    "from_date": 1634813609000,
    "group_by": [
        "service"
    ],
    "values": []
}
```

This is the expected output:

```
service     metric1         metric2
service1    0.65454539894   11
service2    0.52143801191   17
service3    0.56262431074   12
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can give you an idea on how to achieve that:

```py
import os
import json
from pprint import pprint


def get_series_data(serie):
    service_name = None
    pointlist = None
    scope = serie.get("scope")
    if scope:
        service_name = scope.split(":")[-1]
    pointlist_raw = serie.get("pointlist")
    if pointlist_raw:
        pointlist = [x[1] for x in pointlist_raw]
    return service_name, pointlist

def metric_1(data):
    # Return average
    return sum(data) / len(data)

def metric_2(data):
    # Return sum
    return sum(data)

def metric_3(x, y):
    # Return percentage
    return (x / y) * 100


if __name__ == "__main__":

    files = ["metric1.json", "metric2.json"]
    result = {}

    # Every file represents a metric
    # Let's loop over files i.e. metrics
    for file in files:
        # Read from file
        with open(file, "r") as f_in:
            data = json.load(f_in)
        # Get metric name
        metric = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        # Parse JSON data
        series = data.get("series")
        if series:
            for serie in series:
                service_name, pointlist = get_series_data(serie)
                if service_name and pointlist:
                    # If service_name not in result, create it
                    if service_name not in result:
                        result[service_name] = {}
                    # If metric not in service, create it
                    if metric not in result[service_name]:
                        result[service_name][metric] = []
                    # Add data to a list that we will later process depending
                    # on the metric type
                    result[service_name][metric].extend(pointlist)

    # Process metrics for each service
    for service, metrics in result.items():
        for metric in metrics:
            data = result[service][metric]
            if metric == "metric1":
                result[service][metric] = metric_1(data)
            elif metric == "metric2":
                result[service][metric] = metric_2(data)

    # Add a new metric
    for service, metrics in result.items():
        metrics["metric3"] = metric_3(metrics["metric1"], metrics["metric2"])
                
    pprint(result)
```

Result:

```py
{'service1': {'metric1': 0.7638489794123621,
              'metric2': 11,
              'metric3': 6.944081631021473},
 'service2': {'metric1': 0.5214380119113328,
              'metric2': 17,
              'metric3': 3.06728242300784},
 'service3': {'metric1': 0.5626243107461852,
              'metric2': 12,
              'metric3': 4.688535922884877}}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to python and couldn't adapt in case there are more metric files, with different metrics.

Tried to test with other metric files with the same structure, for example metric3.json(with float values) and another metric4.json(with integer values). And make a new metric, for example metric 5(percentage) which would be the values of services found in the metric2.json file divided by the values of metric2.json * 100((metric4/metric2)*100). But I could not...

Comment: @RWagner No worries, everyone has to start somewhere, don't feel bad about it. I'll update my answer to include percentage and you can learn from it.

Comment: @RWagner Updated and added some comments to explain what's going on in each step.

Comment: Forgiveness for the delay. I had another problem, I got involved in another focus and ended up delaying the deal with it.

I have another problem, sometimes some pointlists have null values and I need to remove them from the average calculation. It is generating an error and they cannot influence the calculation, as the average is a division by the length of the pointlist. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'` 

I edited the example file(metric1.json) from the initial post to illustrate the problem.